# AES 256 GCM Java Implementation

Tags: java, encryption, aes, cryptojs, aes-gcm

I'm trying to rewrite the following implementation of AES-256-GCM encryption from NodeJS to Java.

[Packet description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbep9.png)

Im getting a different output, specifically the auth tag part. From the looks of it, the Java libs dont have any methods to fetch the auth tag, and my attempt to substring it from the output fails. Also, I'm not actually sure that the first AES encryption with the public key (generating a random buffer for GCM) works the same as the NodeJS counterpart.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

NodeJS:

```
public encryptPassword(password: string, encryptionKey: string, encryptionKeyId: string): { time: string, encrypted: string } {
    const randKey = crypto.randomBytes(32);
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12);
    const rsaEncrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt({
      key: Buffer.from(encryptionKey, 'base64').toString(),
      // @ts-ignore
      padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
    }, randKey);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', randKey, iv);
    const time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000).toString();
    cipher.setAAD(Buffer.from(time));
    const aesEncrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(password, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);
    const sizeBuffer = Buffer.alloc(2, 0);
    sizeBuffer.writeInt16LE(rsaEncrypted.byteLength, 0);
    const authTag = cipher.getAuthTag();
    return {
      time,
      encrypted: Buffer.concat([
        Buffer.from([1, encryptionKeyId]),
        iv,
        sizeBuffer,
        rsaEncrypted, authTag, aesEncrypted])
        .toString('base64'),
    };
  }
```

Java:

```
 private static Pair<Long, String> encryptPaswword(String password, String encryptionPubKey, String encryptionKeyId) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidCipherTextException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    byte[] passwordAsByte = password.getBytes();
    String decoededPubKey = new String(Base64.decode(encryptionPubKey, Base64.NO_WRAP), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    decoededPubKey = decoededPubKey.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    decoededPubKey = decoededPubKey.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] randKey = new byte[32];
    random.nextBytes(randKey);
    byte[] iv = new byte[12];
    random.nextBytes(iv);
    long date = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

    ByteBuffer header = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    header.put(Integer.valueOf(1).byteValue());
    header.put(Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(encryptionKeyId)).byteValue());
    ByteBuffer timeAAD = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
    timeAAD.put(String.valueOf(date).getBytes());

    X509EncodedKeySpec publicSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(decoededPubKey, Base64.NO_WRAP));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
    rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    byte[] rsaEncrypted = rsaCipher.doFinal(randKey);

    ByteBuffer sizeBuff = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    sizeBuff.put(Integer.valueOf(rsaEncrypted.length).byteValue());

    final Cipher gcmCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
    GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(16 * Byte.SIZE, iv);
    gcmCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(randKey, "AES"), parameterSpec);
    gcmCipher.updateAAD(timeAAD);
    byte[] gcmText= gcmCipher.doFinal(passwordAsByte);

    ByteBuffer result = ByteBuffer.allocate(2+12+2+256+gcmText.length);
    result.put(header);
    result.put(iv);
    result.put(sizeBuff);
    result.put(rsaEncrypted);
    result.put(Arrays.copyOfRange(gcmText, gcmText.length - (16 / Byte.SIZE), gcmText.length));
    result.put(Arrays.copyOfRange(gcmText, 0, gcmText.length - (16 / Byte.SIZE)));

    return new Pair(new Long(date), Base64.encodeToString(result.array(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
```

Comment: Standard encryption/decryption algorithms must work in the same way irrespective to platforms or languages. To ensure that you have to check with appropriate test-vectors for your particular algorithm (usually supplied with the developer or certifying authority).

Comment: Because you set the current time in seconds as the additional authenticated data(AAD), you will always get a different tag except in the unlikely even that you run the code more than once within the same second. And since you don't include that timestamp in your "packet" there is no convenient way for the decryption side to authenticate it. Why authenticate it if you don't send it? Also, your encoding of the RSA output length is wrong, but it will work for RSA key sizes less than 2041 bits. Finally, your calculations for the size of the tag in the Java Arrays.copy are incorrect.

Comment: i do pass the time afterwards unencrypted as part of the message. when validating the results between Node and Java im setting the values (time and random buffers) to validate the results. could you please give me the correct size for the auth tag? and encoding of the RSA size?